# Rails 4 / Ruby 2: Saving nested attributes does not work as expected

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I am trying to save the attributes of an assignment-model through a form for a person-model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :assignment, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :assignment, allow_destroy: true
end

class Assignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :person
  belongs_to :project
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reverse_assignments, class_name:  'Assignment'
end

class PersonsController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @person = Person.new
  end

  def create
    @person = Person.build(person_params)
    @person.build_assignment(assignment_params) # Shouldn't this be obsolete?
    redirect_to root_url
  end

  private

    def person_params
      params.require(:person).permit(:name, assignment_attributes: [:id, :project_id])
    end

    def assignment_params
      params.require(:assignment).permit(:person_id, :project_id) # Only needed because of the "obsolete" line
    end
end

class AssignmentsController < ApplicationController
end
```

This is the form (slim-html):

```
= form_for(@person) do |f|
  = f.text_field :name
  = fields_for :assignment do |r|
    = r.collection_select :project_id, Project.order(:name), :id, :name
  = f.submit 'Save'
```

Creating the assignment through the project-form works, but only by including a second line in the PersonsController's create action. However, shouldn't the first line suffice, because I already included the assignment_params in the person_params? I am asking, because I have issues updating the assignment through an edit-person-form which uses very similar code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
= form_for(@person) do |f|
  = f.text_field :name
  = f.fields_for :assignment do |r|
    = r.collection_select :project_id, Project.order(:name), :id, :name
  = f.submit 'Save'
```

Try adding the `f.fields_for`

You may also want to add this to your "new" action:

```
def new
   @person = Person.new
   @person.build_assignment
end
```

This builds the ActiveRecord object for assignment, which is then passed through the nested attributes to the other model :)

Comment: This is how I had that line before, but with the added "f." the assignment-fields are not rendered at all. Maybe this hints to another problem with my code?

Comment: Have you built the object in the new action that your form is on? Like this:

def new
   @ person = Person.new
   @ person.assignment.build
end

Comment: Thanks, that's it! I declared "@person = Person.new" in the new-action but I forgot "@person.build_assignment" (it has to be "build" with underscore instead of ".build", because of the "has_one" declaration). Now it also works with the added "f."

Comment: What you received in a few minutes took us a day to work out ;) That's how I was so sure about it :) Glad we could help -- I'll add the fix to the answer

Comment: Before asking here, I have been troubled with this for quite a while, too :-) Thank you so much for the quick response!

Comment: Just a little app for the website of a customer who wants to enable his external employees to register for projects.

Comment: Nice! It's always good when you can make something epic for people!